# How to trace steps in SQL profiler for only particular application

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-profiler

We using a third party company software that talk to SQL database and retreives and inserts all the information.

When user uses this software sometimes it freezes at particular step. 
I need to troubleshoot it and find out why it happens.

For that I am using SQL Profiler to see what query causes this bottleneck. 
But how would I trace steps only for that particular software and only for particular user? I dont want to see all other information.

[image]

I am able to filter NTUserName, which I am assuming its just UserName, correct?
But how can I find out what is the ApplicationName?

If I ran this query I see 13 different applications, including Microsoft Office, Report Server etc. None of them sounds lile the name of the software we use. (MGA Systems. Insurance Management System)

```
select distinct 
    program_name
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where is_user_process = 1;
```

Comment: The ApplicationName will be the value specified in the connection string, or if none is specified, a default value that varies depending on the client API.  For example, SqlClient will use the generic ".Net SqlClient Data Provider'" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the username(s) of the people using the app.  Then, where you are, you enter their username in `NTUsername > Like > [User Name without the domain if they are on the same network]` for windows AD connection strings, or the same steps for `username` instead of `ntsurename` if it is a sqlserver user.  You can then filter their queries coming in.

Comment: Thank you guys, also hostname helped a lot. And yes, the application name is ".Net SqlClient Data Provider'". Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

That Is the only way I know of. Just have the profiler running then have the person run the application and look at the times closest to when it ran to get the name of the application. You could also filter it by the Database name that it touches that way be a way to trim it down even further. Profiler is tricky sometimes and to get the information you want you need to keep messing with the filters. Sorry I can't be more help profiler is ornery.